# Linq Group by won't work on multiple columns vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a table like this:

```
PRO_ID     CATEGORY      FINALLY_OK
200          1             55
200          1             60
200          2             65
200          2             80
250          1             55
250          1             60
250          2             65
250          2             80
```

Here is my code :

```
   CType(grdQuality.DataSource, DataView).Table.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)
   .Select(Function(item) New With {.Ok = CType(item.Item("FINALLY_OK"), Decimal), .PRO_ID = item.Item("PRO_ID"), .Category = item.Item("CATEGORY")})
   .GroupBy(Function(item) New With {.PRO_ID = item.PRO_ID, .Category = item.Category})
   .Select(Function(item) New With {item.Key.PRO_ID, item.Key.Category, .AVG = item.Average(Function(i) i.Ok)})
```

but this returns all columns again and `group by` does not work properly

is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an anonymous type to group, but you're not making any of those properties *key* properties... which means they aren't used in the equality tests. Try this:

```
.GroupBy(Function(item) New With { Key .PRO_ID = item.PRO_ID, Key .Category = item.Category})
```

(You won't see that in C# samples, as *all* properties in C# anonymous types are implicitly key properties.)